# Cant disable permanently power management on WiFi

Tags: wireless, power-management

So I have a problem with my wifi, every time I reboot my system the power management is again 'On'. I have trier to create a "wireless" file the following code inside but no luck in this location /etc/pm/power.d :

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iwconfig wlo1 power off
```

What im a missing?

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @WildMan 16.04, I'll edit the post

Comment: I posted the what should be the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ubuntu 16.04 and above run this command to turn off power management.

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Reboot

Answer (score 0):

I had a PCI wireless card that would drop its connection after 20 minutes or so after installing 16.04 lts. I lived with this for a few weeks and then went searching for a solution. Was it driver(s)? No. I eventually determined that it was a feature, power-saving. I found out how to turn it off using iwconfig. But how to make this permanent...

The following link managed to get me out of the weeds -

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269661/how-to-turn-off-wireless-power-management-permanently

with the following answer:

Go to the directory

/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/

and open the file

default-wifi-powersave-on.conf

By default it is wifi.powersave = 3 so just change it to wifi.powersave = 2.

Save, exit and reboot. [edit: 2 is the correct value, not 0.]

And to check this, use tlp-stat --rfkill