# how to reset CPU max speed?

Tags: cpufreq

I've recently had a problem where my cpu was running at min speed constantly. This resulted in a very slow laptop and I found an article where one said it could be solved with this command:

this is the command I executed:

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

link to the thread: [Cant disable permanently power management on WiFi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905273/cant-disable-permanently-power-management-on-wifi/905279#905279?newreg=381ba82d79a143b38b29f735d4af6a35)

After doing so, my cpu now runs at a max freq of 3500MHz instead of the standard 2500MHz. This results in overheating and I'd like to reset the max freq back to standards. Any idea how? I've tried resetting in BIOS but unsuccesfully.

cheers!

Comment: you sure you used this command for the cpu? it's like it's for the wifi

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/929884/how-to-set-performance-instead-of-powersave-as-default/936488#936488

Answer (score 0):

This reverts your change:

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 2/wifi.powersave = 3/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

What you did was edit the file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` and search (the `s/../`) for `wifi.powersave = 3` and then replace it (the `/.../` after the `s/..`) with `wifi.powersave = 2` so all that needs to be done is switch the search and replace parameter.

This edit has nothing to do with CPU frequencies though.

> [WiFi Powersave](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/reference/snap-configuration/wifi-powersave) is a feature that allows a device to suspend its radio activity after a fixed period of inactivity. The device remains idle for a fixed time, usualy about 100ms, and once it is reached it wakes up to check if the infrastructure has any packets queued up for it.

---

> wifi.powersave can have the following value:

```
NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_DEFAULT (0): use the default value
NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_IGNORE (1): don't touch existing setting
NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_DISABLE (2): disable powersave
NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_ENABLE (3): enable powersave
```

Regarding CPU frequenty. Maybe you also edited  `/etc/default/cpufrequtils`. Check if it exists and if so what is set for `GOVERNOR`.It should be one of: userspace conservative powersave ondemand performance